# Change the background of a button on hovering with transparent background

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I think the title is pretty clear to be honest so what I want is that when the user hovers over the button the background image changes. I did not work with specific classes because the background: transparent messes it up.

This is the code for the button:

```
<button type="submit" style="border: 0; padding: 0px; margin-top: -1px; background: transparent">
    <img src="../images/login open.png" alt="Inloggen" width="130" height="29" />
</button>
```

Thanks for looking into it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not using a transparent PNG?  You can avoid using background:transparent altogether and instead, just use button:hover to change the background.

HTML:

```
 <button type="submit"></button>
```

CSS:

```
 button {
 background:url(yourImage.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 height: 29px;
 width: 130px;
 border:none;
 }

 button:hover {
 background:url(yourImage.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Hc5Dz/